# Working with date time in web api

Tags: mysql, rest, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-web-api2, datetime-format

I have created a `WEB API`using `MySQL` database. The table includes the data about the meter's serial numbers it's signal strength values and the date time on which the signal strength has comes. For now i am successful in getting data by sending the meter's serial number.

Now I am also sending the date time parameter to it also. But it's not working for me. Below is what i have done.

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetByMsn(string msn, DateTime dt)
        {
            try
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Found, medEntitites.tj_xhqd.Where(m=> m.msn == msn).Where(a=> a.date_time < dt ));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
            }
        }
```

The `WebApiConfig` file includes

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
       name: "GetByMsn",
       routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{msn}/{dt}",
       defaults: null,
       constraints: new { msn = @"^[0-9]+$" , dt = @"^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$" }
       );
```

After that I am passing the URL like `http://localhost:14909/api/meters/GetByMsn/000029000033/2017-10-06T07:52:27`

The error I am getting is `A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).`

For this I have also searched for the solutions but couldn't find out the correct one. Also I have replaced `:` in date time but still it's not working for me

**Update 1**

While passing only date`2017-10-06` it works for me but when I append it with time it doesn't works

For a quick check I checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19692501/creating-a-route-that-can-accept-a-datetime-in-the-uri-with-asp-net-web-api-2-at) but still i am unable to solve the solution.

I must be missing something that I don't know

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching I finally found a solution.

I have changed the predefined disallowed/invalid characters in my Web.config. Under , added the following: `<httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,%,&amp;,*,\,?" />.` I've removed the `:` from the standard list of invalid characters.

For more information see this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33345318/6854117)